# How to show multiple records with same name?

Tags: php, sql

I have a database tables containing four fields.

`id` is my `primary key` and the rest of the fields are: name, address and phone number of the restaurant accordingly. Now, I have many restaurants belonging to different chains, so I saved them using same `name` and their `address` and `phone no` fields look like this:

**This is how my database looks like:**

```
id |     name    | address  | Phone_no |

1  | restaurant1 | address1 | XXXXXX1  |
2  | restaurant1 | address2 | XXXXXX2  |
3  | restaurant1 | address3 | XXXXXX3  |
4  | restaurant2 | address1 | XXXXXX1  |
5  | restaurant2 | address2 | XXXXXX2  |
6  | restaurant3 | address1 | XXXXXX1  |
7  | restaurant4 | address1 | XXXXXX1  |
```

**How I want to show it In my page :**

```
 |     name    | address  | Phone_no |

 | restaurant1 | address1 | XXXXXX1  |
 |             | address2 | XXXXXX2  |
 |             | address3 | XXXXXX3  |
 | restaurant2 | address1 | XXXXXX1  |
 |             | address2 | XXXXXX2  |
 | restaurant3 | address1 | XXXXXX1  |
 | restaurant4 | address1 | XXXXXX1  |
```

Now I want to show it using PHP, with name, their address and phone number, **but name should be displayed only once**.

**this is my PHP code:**

```
    <?php
    //this is my query.
    $query = "SELECT * FROM details WHERE cat_id = $id GROUP BY name";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    ?>
      <table>
         <tr>
           <td><?php echo cfirst($row['name'] ?></td>
           <td><?php echo row['address'] ?></td>
           <td><?php echo row['phone'] ?></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
   <?php } ?>
```

**The result of this query:**

```
 |     name    | address  | Phone_no |

 | restaurant1 | address1 | XXXXXX1  |
 | restaurant2 | address1 | XXXXXX1  |
 | restaurant3 | address1 | XXXXXX1  |
 | restaurant4 | address1 | XXXXXX1  |
```

Comment: Where are you displaying this? Are you running it in a while loop?? Show some code

Comment: If you use WHERE name = 'SALT 'N PEPPER' it will give an error because you end your query before PEPPER. Use double quotation marks.. WHERE name = "SALT 'N PEPPER"

Comment: Does your php code echo out any results?? Because I see in your code you specified a condition for your while loop but have not encased your result with curly braces?? "{}" As for giving the header for the restuarant, just exclude the name from the while loop as a header for the contents..

Comment: yes it is echo results but it only show one result i want it like this.Restaurant A:
123 B town.
Restaurant B:
123 C town.
Restaurant C:
1 A Town.
2 B Town .
3 C Town. and it is show result like this Restaurant A:
123 B town
Restaurant B:
123 C town
Restaurant C:
1 A Town

Comment: Check the code i answered that will sort out the loop, implement seans answer into it.

Comment: This question has been edited please reopen this question just for knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First You have to Remove:

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM details WHERE cat_id = $id";
```

This group by is just removing address of restaurant with multiple address.you have to do it in you code in my view.

```
    <?php
    $last_name = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    ?>
      <table>
         <tr>
         <?php if ($last_name == ''){?>
           <td><?php echo cfirst($row['name'] ?></td>
          <?php 
                $last_name = $row['name']; 
                } elseif($last_name != $row['name']){
          ?>
           <td><?php echo cfirst($row['name'] ?></td>
          <?php }else{ ?>
           <td></td>
          <?php } ?>
           <td><?php echo row['address'] ?></td>
           <td><?php echo row['phone'] ?></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
   <?php } ?>
```

This will solve your problem just adjust your html accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You'll still need to get all the rows from SQL, so I think this is something you could fix on the PHP side of things. So Maybe you have a table that has the Name column spanning multiple rows, so that you have unique addresses, but only show the name once?

```
$command = "select * from table_name";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$command);
$last = "";
$count = 0;
while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($data['name'] == $last){
        //print table row
        ++$count;
    } else {
        //echo new <TD> cell that has rowspan="$count"
        //print table row
        $count = 0;
    $last = $data['name'];
    }
}
```

Very rough, didn't test.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

1. Query the table for all restaurants and order by restaurant name
2. Loop through all records and at the end of each loop, store the `$last_restaurant` name
3. In the loop, if the `$last_restaurant` name is the same as the next restaurant name, echo out just the address and phone
4. In the loop, if the `$last_restaurant` name is NOT the same as the next restaurant name echo out the all information

[**Here's**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CWB2CI) a working example, try to implement it within your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test where cat_id = $id");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){


$name = $row['name'];
$address = $row['address'];
$phone = $row['phone'];
?>
<doctype! html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Name: <?php echo $name ?> <br>
Address: <?php echo $address ?><br>
Phone: <?php echo $phone ?><br><br>
</body>
</html> 
<?php
}
?>
```

Output:

Name: rest1

Address: 23 rose street

Phone: 123125325

Name: rest2

Address: 23 bank street

Phone: 24343532523

Name: rest1

Address: 25 green street

Phone: 53425435432

Name: rest2

Address: 54 rover street

Phone: 6434532